# Call a function with 2 Variables

Tags: vba, database, function, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I'm trying to create a dynamic function that's based off on what dropdown you interact with on a form. I need to pass the name of the dropdown to the function along with the form name when I call it.

Here's my current setup which only calls the funciton that passes the form name:

```
Private Sub KitchenMainCode_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Call Populate([Form])
End Sub

Populate(frm As Form)
'do stuff
End Function
```

I have 8 dropdowns which means I have to copy paste 8 batches of the same code which isn't ideal, Ideally I would like something like this:

```
 Private Sub KitchenMainCode_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
        Call Populate([Form], [control.name OR "KitchenMainCode"])
    End Sub
    
    Populate(frm As Form AND dropdown name as name)
    frm.name.value = xyz
    End Function
```

Even at the least, if I can pass a string Its easier to make 8 Mousedown events than 8 unique functions, which is nearly 50 lines (x8).

Every time I google this, its bringing lots of Excel stuff & for some reason the code that's used isn't compatible with access (probably my issue) but they're both VBA scripts.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```vb
Private Sub KitchenMainCode_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Call Populate(Me, Me.ActiveControl, Button, Shift, X, Y)
End Sub


Private Sub Populate(frm As Form, ctl As Control, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    ' do stuff
End Function
```

Or you could implement `WithEvents`. An example can be found in my project [VBA.ModernTheme](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernTheme).

To call a function:

```vb
Private Sub KitchenMainCode_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Dim Result As Long  ' as the function returns.

    Result = Populate(Me, Me.ActiveControl, Button, Shift, X, Y)
End Sub


Private Function Populate(frm As Form, ctl As Control, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single) As Long
    ' do stuff

    Populate = SomeResultValue
End Function
```

Comment: I seem to be getting a compile error with this, "Expected list separator or )". I've played around it and cannot get this to work. I also would call it with this 'Call Populate([Form])' but I cannot get the code to save first, its just red.

Comment: Yes, remains from copy-paste, sorry. Corrected.

Comment: 'Code Dropdowns
Private Sub KitchenMainCode_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
        Call Populate(Me, Me.ActiveControl, Button, Shift, X, Y)
End Sub
Private Sub Populate(frm As Form, ctl As Control, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
  MsgBox (ctl)
End Sub

Comment: Above is the exact code copied from my DB and Its still not working unfortunately, I appreciate the help though, Also done msgbox(ctl.name) & msgbox("string")

Comment: Can't tell. Works great here for a textbox.

Comment: My apologies, I don't know what I did but copying and pasting it back in works. I made no changes. Anyway I appreciate the help! How would I call this if it was in a function? Call FunctionName([Form], [Ctl])?

Comment: See extended answer, please.